# Asynchronously loaded content not updated on file change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, virtual-machine

I have simple container into which I am asynchronously loading contents from simple html view files using jQuery .load() function.

After changing the contents of any of view files, changes are not being displayed in the browser.

I thought it might be a problem with content being persistent in DOM after being hidden and shown again, but even after purging the html of container and loading it from scratch, the the content is still not updated.

I am using VMware virtual machine with Debian 7 and folder sharing, so I thought that maybe it's an issue with shared folder synchronisation, but viewing the html files inside VM console shows that their content is updated correctly.

There's no caching involved, so I don't know what could be the issue here.

Here are some code samples:

the js is quite complex, but here's the part directly responsible for loading the file on click:

```
container.load(href + '.html',
    function(){
        self.open(id);
    });
```

contents are loaded from file like: about.html

```
<p class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, autem.
</p>
```

and here's a part of my index file:

```
<div class="inner-wrapper" >
    <a href="about" class="box-anchor" data-id="about">
        <h2 class="box-title">About</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="content-wrapper" id="about"><!--content is being loaded here--></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you say that "there's no caching involved"?

Comment: What I mean by that is that I don't have any caching configured on the server.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @Nicolas but the *browser* will cache stuff fetched via GET requests unless the server is explicitly telling it not to do so.

Comment: or the url has a cachebuster query string like a timestamp added to it ...`?_=45876553333`.  Where's the code?

Comment: Haven't thought of that... It appears to have solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

So I have included a cachebuster query following [charlietfl's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787073/asynchronously-loaded-content-not-updated-on-file-change?noredirect=1#comment43984452_27787073). It fixed the issue.
This is what the updated code looks like:

```
container.load(href + '.html?' + (new Date).getTime(),
    function(){
    self.open(id);
});
```